# Visualforce Query Not Displaying

Tags: visualforce, soql

I'm having problems with getting my data to display on my visualforce page.  The logs show data inside the variable, but when I try to display the data in a table nothing shows but the headers. Thanks in Advance.

**Controller:**
public with sharing class RelationshipManagerAccountUtils {

```
private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
public List<Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c> searchResults {get; set;}
public string searchText {get; set;}

public RelationshipManagerAccountUtils(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}

public PageReference search() {
    String qry = 'SELECT Id, Account__r.name,Account__r.id, Recruiter__r.name, RM_Rank__c, Relationship_Manager_Contact__r.name FROM Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c '+'WHERE Account__r.name LIKE \'%' +searchText+'%\' ORDER BY Account__r.name';
    searchResults = Database.query(qry);
    System.debug(searchResults);
    return null;
}
public PageReference save() {

    try {
        update searchResults;
    } catch(DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }

    return new PageReference('/' +ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
}

public PageReference cancel() {
    return new PageReference('/' +ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
}
```

`}`

```
<b>Visualforce Page:</b>
<apex:page standardController="Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c" extensions="RelationshipManagerAccountUtils">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Relationship Manager Account" subtitle="{!Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c.Account__r.name}"/>
    <b>Hello {!$User.FirstName}! Welcome to the RM Accounts Page.</b>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="RM Account Search" mode="edit">
    <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save Records"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel for="searchText">Account</apex:outputLabel>               
                <apex:panelGroup >
                <apex:inputText id="searchText" value="{!searchText}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" rerender="block" status="status"/>
                </apex:panelGroup>               
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection><br/>
        <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Searching... please wait..."/>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Results" id="resultsBlock" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!searchResults}" var="accts" >
                <apex:column value="{!accts.Account__r.name}" headerValue="ISO Account"/>
                <apex:column value="{!accts.Relationship_Manager_Contact__r.name}" headerValue="Relationship Manager"/>
                <apex:column value="{!accts.RM_Rank__c}" headerValue="RM Rank"/>
                <apex:column value="{!accts.Recruiter__r.name}" headerValue="Recruiter"/>               
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Relationship Manager Account">
    <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2"> 
            <apex:outputField title="Relationship Manager" label="Relationship Manager" value="{!Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c.Relationship_Manager_Contact__r.name}" />
            <apex:outputField title="RM Rank" value="{!Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c.RM_Rank__c}" />
            <apex:outputField title="Recruiter" value="{!Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c.Recruiter__r.name}" />
            <apex:outputField title="Account" value="{!Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c.Account__r.name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I know there is a redundant page block at the bottom as I was just trying things out and it wasn't hurting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that your search button rerenders something called "block"  but your results appears to be in a block called "resultsBlock".  Try updating your button to rerender the "resultsBlock" instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I couldn't figure it out for the life of me.  That totally makes sense now.